# Concurrently processing several files in Go

Tags: go

I have a system that receives hundreds of files per day for processing.  I am relatively new to GO and was looking at building something to concurrently process the files.  The workflow looks like this:  Get list of files, for each file in list ->check file size->check file hash->Process file->Add processed file name and processing time to database-> Send file to destination.  The process happens sequentially but I would like to process the files concurrently or in a fanout pattern.

Right now I have something that looks like the following:

```
err := filepath.Walk("/uploads", func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
    filesToTransfer = append(filesToTransfer, path)
    return nil
})

if err != nil {
    ErrorLogger.Println(err)
}


for _, uploadedFile := range filesToTransfer {
   checkFileSize(uploadedFile.Name(), expectedSize)
   checkFileHash(uploadedFile.Name())
   readFileData(uploadedFile.Name())
   addProcessedToDatabase(uploadedFile.Name())
   sendFile(uploadedFile.Name())        
}
```

Would wrapping the 5 functions in an anonymous goroutine function accomplish what I am trying to do?  Something like this:

```
err := filepath.Walk("/uploads", func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
    filesToTransfer = append(filesToTransfer, path)
    return nil
})

if err != nil {
    ErrorLogger.Println(err)
}
  var wg WaitGroup

  for _, fileToTransfer := range filesToTransfer {
     wg.Add(1)
     go func(uploadFile string) {
         checkFileSize(uploadFile, expectedSize)
         checkFileHash(uploadedFile)
         readFileData(uploadedFile)
         addProcessedToDatabase(uploadedFile)
         sendFile(uploadedFile)   
         wg.Done()
     }(fileToTransfer)   
   wg.Wait()  
}
```

Edit: I modified the way I am gathering files in the directory.  I could not figure out how to get an fs.FileInfo type to pass to my goroutine and made the correction pointed out in the comments.

Comment: See [Closures and Goroutines](https://go.dev/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines) and make the fix suggested there.   Depending on the size `bigListOfFiles`, you may want to use a [worker pool](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgo%5D+worker+pool) instead of a goroutine per file.

Comment: It's a great use case for goroutines!

Comment: For doing the work pool would I need to get the list of all the files currently in the directory and then feed that to a jobs channel prior to executing the workflow I outlined?

Comment: Yes,  you'd add to the wait group and start the workers first, then write the file paths to it,  then close the channel.   Then wait for a wait group to make sure the channel is drained and the work is finished.

Comment: [This article](https://itnext.io/explain-to-me-go-concurrency-worker-pool-pattern-like-im-five-e5f1be71e2b0) is pretty good at explaining the worker pool model for doing this.